# MAvensMate IDE to Sublime text for salesforce IDE

Tags: mavensmate, force.com-ide

Anyone please provide me any guide line for Sublime text with MavensMate IDE with salesforce .

I Have Sublime text but i am unable to configure with MavensMate with force.IDE ..

I have Mavensmate and launch mavensamate ..its closing every time..

Could you please help on this..

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: What do you mean you launch MavensMate? It is a plugin to Sublime. Once installed, you should see a MavensMate option in the menu. The MM website has a lot of information on how to install and use.

Comment: You won't be using the force.IDE with maven's mate. Launch sublime text.

Comment: Thanks for your input @DanielHoechst..But my question iam not able to see MavensMate editor or App.. unable to launch it ...